# Can we run queries from the Custom UDF in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

guys I am newbie to Hive and have some doubts in it.

Normally we write custom UDF in Hive for the particular number of columns. (Consider UDF is in Java). Means it performs some operation on that particular column.

I am thinking that can we write such UDF through which we can give the particular column as a input to some query and can we return that query from UDF which will execute on Hive CLI by taking the column as a input?

Can we do this? If yes please suggest me.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box because as the Hive query is running, there has been a plan already built that is going to execute. What you suggest is to dynamically change that plan while it is running, which is not only hard because the plan is already built, but also because the Hadoop MapReduce jobs are already running.

What you can do is have your initial Hive query output new Hive queries to a file, then have some sort of bash/perl/python script that goes through that and formulates new Hive queries and passes them to the CLI.